# Fitting a page into IFRAME

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a newbie in html,css,javascript. And I am trying to load a page as a submenu item in my page. I have this code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homePage.css">
        <title> Sample Website </title>
        <script>
            function showPicture(value)
            {
                if(value == "true")
                {
                    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = '';
                    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML 
                            += '<iframe id="Picturebox" width = "76%" height = "545" src="menu1.html"></iframe>';
                }
                else
                {
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = '';
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id = "Header">
            <h1> SAMPLE WEBSITE </h1>

        </div>      
        <div id = "Banner">
            <img id ="imgBanner" src = "./images/images.jpeg" />
        </div>      
        <div id="container">
        <div id = "menu">
            <table cellpadding="15">
                <tr> 
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" onclick="showPicture('true')">Menu 1</a> 

                    </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr> 
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" onclick="showPicture('false')">Menu 2</a>
                    </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr> 
                    <td>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="showPicture('false')">Menu 3</a>
                    </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr> 
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" onclick="showPicture('false')">Menu 4</a>
                    </td> 
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div> 
        <div id="content"></div>
        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

### menu1.html

```
<html>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=80%,height=80%, scale=0.5">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="subPage.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Menu 1 </h1>
<div id = "UnderLine"></div>
<p>     Hello!,
        this is a sample page having a heading,some content and 6 pictures .
</p>
<div id = "UnderLine"></div><br/>
<h4> Images </h4>
<div id = "UnderLine"></div><br/>
<div class="imgbox" style="position:relative;">
<img id = "pictures" src="./images/p (1).jpg" name=""/>
<img id = "pictures" src="./images/p (2).jpg" name=""/>
<img id = "pictures" src="./images/p (3).jpg" name=""/>
<img id = "pictures" src="./images/p (4).jpg" name=""/>
<img id = "pictures" src="./images/p (5).jpg" name=""/>
<img id = "pictures" src="./images/p (6).jpg" name=""/>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

here I tried maximum of my effort . But the `IFrame` loads the page with a horizontal scroll bar. I need help to **make it fit inside**. Is there any way to obtain the same. I googled but some or all of them saying about width. Not about height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<iframe scrolling="no" ....
```

read this doc: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_scrolling.asp

Comment: If your iframe content has a specific width that is greater than iframe width... of course!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<iframe id="Picturebox" width = "76%" height = "545" src="menu1.html" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Comment: give the frame height as page height